# How to call a variable inGroovy?

Tags: groovy

I i'm trying to call a variable in groovy.
my variable is a property value from soapui

so i try this:

i want to open this page: http://www.google.com/trends/2014/
i have the year 2014 in my property value.

```
def Year = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue( "Year" )
java.awt.Desktop.desktop.browse "http://www.google.com/trends/"+Year+"/"
```

I don't know how to call the variable Year in the url, can someone help me please.
is this correct?

When i  run the code i have this error: `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.awt.Desktop.browse() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values:[http://www.google.com/trends/2014/] Possible solutions: browse(java.net.URI), isCase(java.lang.Object),` use([Ljava.lang.Object;)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browse takes a uri, not a string... Just do

```
def Year = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue( "Year" )
java.awt.Desktop.desktop.browse(new URI("http://www.google.com/trends/$year/"))
```

Comment: thank you it works, i was looking for hours and hours